# Delete and Update SSRS report using powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have multiple SSRS reports deployed in different folders on the server.
I want to delete some of the reports from these folders. Is there any solution using the PowerShell script to do this? Need help

Comment: Yes. For a more comprehensive answer, you will need to provide more information. That includes what you have tried and what was the result.

Comment: SSRS reports aren't deployed to folders, they're deployed to the dbo.Catalog table in the report server database. Have you tried using the SSRS web APIs?